# How to delete a row when first row second column is same as second rows first column in sql

Tags: sql

How to delete a row if `first row's code column`  *equals* to the `second rows number column` and `second rows' code column` *equals* to the `first row's number column`.

sql must not use loop

use this as sample code

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int, code int, Number int)

Insert into #temp values(1,2,1)
Insert into #temp values(2,1,2)
Insert into #temp values(3,2,3)
Insert into #temp values(4,2,3)
Insert into #temp values(5,2,3)

select * from #temp
```

Comment: How should the results in #temp look like after solution is applied?

Comment: Should first row or second row be deleted? Or should both be deleted?

Comment: Second row should be deleted and i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using. Let me assume that it is SQL Server, then you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) rownum
    from temp
), RowsToDelete
AS(
    SELECT c1.*
    FROM CTE c1
    INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.rownum - c2.rownum = 1 AND c1.number = c2.code
)
DELETE r
FROM temp r
WHERE ID IN  ( SELECT ID 
               FROM RowsToDelete);
```

For the sample data, you posted this will delete only one row, which is:

```
ID     CODE    NUMBER 
2       1        2
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd9a0/1)

Comment: Thanks .This is really works for me   +20 . But i couldn't vote u up.. bcz my repuation is o.. so increase my reputation via this questioon

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a join to get the rows you want to delete using the criteria you've specified:

```
delete t1
from #temp t1
inner join #temp t2
    on t1.code = t2.Number and t2.code = t1.Number
```

Comment: This command delete both the rows similar . But i need to delete only one rows...

Answer (score 0):

delete t1

from #temp t1

where exists(

select * from #temp t2

where t1.code = t2.Number and t2.code = t1.Number and t2.Id > t1.Id

)

Comment: This is also works as i want but takes more time than this code 


;WITH CTE
AS
(
   select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) rownum
    from temp
), RowsToDelete
AS(
    SELECT c1.*
    FROM CTE c1
    INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.rownum - c2.rownum = 1 AND c1.number = c2.code
)
DELETE r
FROM temp r
WHERE ID IN  ( SELECT ID 
               FROM RowsToDelete);